# Getting an Error in jquery initialization. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'jquery' of undefined at (index):27

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-promise, es6-modules, es6-class, es6-module-loader

Getting an error in the jquery property declared in paths.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>User Interface</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/node_modules/material-design-lite/dist/material.css"
    />

    <script src="node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/material-design-lite/dist/material.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      System.paths['jquery'] = "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js";
      System.import("src/app.js");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess System.paths is undefined ... try it directly in your Browser console, to get.

Comment: means how i try it directly in browser?

Comment: For instance, if you use Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: Two things, your src to System.js is wrong. Or. You are trying to access System before System.js is completely loaded. 

In both cases when you are trying to assign System.paths['']. System object is not available in browser.